# Vue.js - this.<value>.<value> is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

```
<div class="content-chart">
 <chart :type="'line'" :data="lineData" :options="options"></chart>
</div>
```

Above is the template section for a component and below is the script.

```
<script>
import Chart from 'vue-bulma-chartjs'
import { Tabs, TabPane } from 'vue-bulma-tabs'
export default {
  components: {
    Chart
  },
  data () {
    return {
      persondata: {},
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    let parameter = this.$route.params.id
    axios.get('/api' + parameter.toString()).then(response => {
     this.persondata = response.data
    })
  },
  computed: {
    lineData () {
      var sth = this.person.dates['date-values']
      return {
        labels: [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        datasets: [{
          data: sth,
          label: 'Speed',
        }]
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

So as you see this Vue component renders a chart from Chart.js on the page. The problem is when I get the response from the api and save it to the `this.persondata` variable, when the component is mounted I get `"TypeError: this.persondata.dates is undefined"`. If I do this though:

```
data () {
  return {
    persondata: {
      dates: {
        'date-values': []        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I try to save the `response.data.dates['date-values']` to `this.persondata.dates['date-values']` and insert it into the `dataset.data` in `computed()` I don't get any chart.

What is the problem?

Comment: there is no mention of cardata in your code, problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

computed properties are calculated right away: they are calculated before your Ajax returns.

Since you only populate `persondata` when the Ajax returns, the first time the computed is calculated, `persondata` is `{}` (the value of initialization in `data`).

**Quick fix:** initialize with an empty `dates` object, so the computation doesn't throw that error (giving time for the Ajax to return, which will update the computed property automatically):

```
  data () {
    return {
      persondata: {dates: {}}, // added empty dates property
    }
  },
```

Comment: The message disappeared, however the chart does not update. Vue devtools shows that the computed property was not recalculated and re-rendered.